# Process Explorer: huge I/O bytes with small Network/Disk Bytes

Tags: performance, windows-server-2003, process-explorer

What does it means when process explorer show me a huge I/O Bytes pre second but mean while a low Network and Disk Bytes pre second?

I have a machine here that the process explorer (v14) showing me

- I/O Bytes: 130~600GB/s
- Network Bytes: up to 20MB/s
- Disk Bytes: less then 1MB/s

Comment: As V14 has only just been released: yesterday, you might need to be patient. And checkout http://forum.sysinternals.com

Comment: The number has been here for some time and few versions. The only different is that the old version does not show which is network and disk.